# Wear capabilityClient Nodes are not "nearby"

Tags: android, wear-os

I haven't posted here in a while. Please forgive my lack of clarity at this late hour.

### Situation

I'm wanting to listen to the `capabilityClient` from a wear device to know when a handheld device goes offline (alerting for leaving your phone behind, for practice). So far, my attempts have failed, so I'm reversing the workflow (listening for wear from handheld) to simplify.

I have a physical Pixel 6 (mobile) and a physical Fossil Carlyle HR (watch). They are paired and I use them both nearly daily. They are both connected to ADB and I can monitor their logs with Logcat in Android Studio.

### Problem

I have a somewhat modified version of the [DataLayer Sample project](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/DataLayer) running locally. I first tried setting up a listener for capability changes, but I never got any callbacks when my devices went offline.

I shifted gears to just looking for Nodes, to verify there were findable at all. Sometimes when I query for reachable Nodes it returns the paired device. Sometimes it does not.

It seems my problem querying for Nodes has something to do with the paired device being "nearby", but I'm not certain.

### Code

In MainActivity.kt, I have a button that triggers queryNodes():

```
MainActivity.kt
// Sorry for the gratuitous logging and control statements.
// I've been learning Kotlin as I go, and I forgot the value of the debugger.
...
    private fun queryNodes() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Node Query clicked")
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val nodes = getReachableNodes()
                    .filterValues { MOBILE_CAPABILITY in it }.keys
                Log.d(TAG, "Nodes: " + nodes.toString())
            } catch (cancellationException: CancellationException) {
                throw cancellationException
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Querying nodes failed: $exception")
            }
        }
    }
...
    private suspend fun getReachableNodes(): Map<Node, Set<String>> =
        capabilityClient.getAllCapabilities(CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE)
            .await()
            // Pair the list of all reachable nodes with their capabilities
            .flatMap { (capability, capabilityInfo) ->
                Log.d(TAG, "flat mapping " + capability.toString())
                capabilityInfo.nodes.map { it to capability }
            }
            // Group the pairs by the nodes
            .groupBy(
                keySelector = { it.first },
                valueTransform = { it.second }
            )
            // Transform the capability list for each node into a set
            .mapValues { it.value.toSet() }
...
```

This setup returns an empty list of Nodes.

When I changed the filter to `FILTER_ALL`, I was able to get a Node back. With the debugger I found that the Node's `isNearby` property was `false`. I'm thinking that's why it wasn't "reachable".

### Question

What can I do to make these Nodes reachable? Does it have anything to do with being "nearby"?

Am I barking up the wrong tree with this `CapabilityClient` and listening for capability changes?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the image below, from the [Connectivity](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer#connectivity) guide:

[image: A sample network of nodes with handheld and wearable devices.]

`Watch 1`, `Phone` and `Watch 2` are all  [reachable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityClient#public-static-final-int-filter_reachable) nodes from each other's perspective.

`Phone` and `Watch 1` are [nearby](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node#isNearby()) each other.

---

> What can I do to make these Nodes reachable?

The nodes have to be online and [paired](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer#send-and-sync-with-API): "This API is only available on Wear OS watches and paired Android devices".

> Does it have anything to do with being "nearby"?

No. As per example above, `Watch 2` is reachable from `Phone` or `Watch 1`, but `Watch 2` is not nearby them.

> I'm wanting to listen to the capabilityClient from a wear device to know when a handheld device goes offline (alerting for leaving your phone behind, for practice).

> Am I barking up the wrong tree with this CapabilityClient and listening for capability changes?

Maybe.

- [FILTER_ALL](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityClient#FILTER_ALL) will return all the [nodes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node), even the ones that are not online (not reachable), but I don't see a way of identifying which one of those nodes are offline.
- [FILTER_REACHABLE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/CapabilityClient#FILTER_REACHABLE) will return only the online (reachable) nodes.

It looks like a way is to make two separate calls, each one with a different filter, and subtract the results to figure out the offline ones.

I'd suggest you to raise a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to improve that API, explaining your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you've described makes sense to me and is what I'd expect. In my use case, my devices are essentially `Phone` and `Watch 1`, which is why the behavior is stumping me. From `Phone`, `Watch 1` should be "nearby". Maybe the fact that the wifi is turned on for `Watch 1` (in order to connect to Android Studio) overrides the fact that it's also connected to `Phone` over Bluetooth.

Comment: If I reconfigure my setup so that `Watch 1` is debugging over Bluetooth (as described in [the "Debug over Bluetooth" section of the "Debug a Wear OS app" portion of the Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging#bt-debugging)), I'm able to see that `Watch 1` and `Phone` are nearby. This hasn't been fully confirmed to fix my issue, but it feels like I'm on the right track.

Comment: I think that did it. Debugging `Watch 1` over bluetooth seems to be the key.